# Display custom text when comments are closed

Tags: comments

When I close comments on a post it's showing "Comments are closed". Is there any way to edit this text and show a personal note instead of the pre-configured one?

I would prefer to do this in a 'universal' type of thing, meaning that the same message would appear even if I change the wordpress theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to `comments.php` in your theme - and search for "Comments are closed", you should find it.

You should also be able do this in `functions.php`:

```
function comment_text ($arg) {
$arg['title_reply'] = __('Too Late - Comments are Closed!');
return $arg;
}
add_filter('comment_form_defaults','comment_text');
```

Edit: Just noticed that you want this to work cross theme. So if you go to: `wp-comments-post.php` in the top level of your Wordpress install, you should find it there too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you excuse me, a follow-up question about this.
I tried to enter a custom text inside the div tag on the closed comments section but nothing showed up on the frontend. Have a look at the comments.php code of my theme, maybe it needs a fix or something. link to the code: http://pastebin.com/K2HuTMJ8